# how do I access the value of an attribute inside an object using cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to push the values of an attribute("data-code") into an array using cheerio.  However, I keep getting the error message "allAs[i].attr is not a function"

Here's what I have so far

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const app = express();

app.get('/scrape', (req, res) => {
    const url = 'http://store.emart.com/branch/list.do?id=1702';    

    request(url, (err, response, body) => {
        if(!err) {
            var idList = [];
            console.log(typeof(idList));
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            var allAs = $("a").filter("[data-code]");
            console.log(allAs[0].val);
            for(var i = 0; i < allAs.length; i++){
                //console.log(allAs[i]);
               idList.push(allAs[i].attr("[data-code]"));
            }
            console.log();

            res.send(body);
        } else {
            console.log("problems yo");
        }
    });
});


app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is up and running!!!");
});
```

There should be 330 results pushed into idList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your code, change this:

`idList.push(allAs[i].attr("[data-code]"));`

... to ...

`idList.push(allAs[i].attribs['data-code']);`

—

** It's been a while since I last used cheerio so I'm not sure if this is how it's supposed to be or it's a bug.*

Comment: That was right!  Thanks a bunch.  I didn't realize that attr is NOT a function..even though it actually told me.  I feel relieved..yet embarrassed!